# dashDB query node: Error: [IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/LINUXX8664] SQL0964C The transaction log for the database is full. SQLSTATE=57011

Tags: dashdb

I am using nodeRed and DashDB and now when I am perfomring some inserts on database I am getting the following message on debug for nodered:

```
dashDB query node: Error: [IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/LINUXX8664] SQL0964C The transaction log for the database is full. SQLSTATE=57011
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to commit your data more often. Do you know how much data you are inserting and how often you are committing it?

This article also talks about increasing the size of your log file, but if you are running dashDB on Bluemix you may not have access to this setting:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21365131